# Loading KML file onto Google Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kml

I tried implementing KML in Google Maps fragment following official documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/kml) but it didn't work. There are no errors, map opens but no KML overlay. I know how to load KML from a local file (stored in raw folder), but I'm trying to do the same through URL leading to KML file (stored on GitHub Gist).

Here's the code:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new URL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/...route.kml").openStream();
        KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, inputStream, getApplicationContext());
        layer.addLayerToMap();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the URL for your KML file directly downloads the file?  The URL in your sample code is clearly incomplete, and does not link to a file: " https://gist.githubusercontent.com/...route.kml ", but that might just be an example.  If the URL goes to a GitHub page that shows the file, then GMaps will not able to fetch it... the URL needs to point directly at the file, so it can be fetched correctly.

Comment: @C.A. I deliberately cut out the part of the URL, so it isn't public. The URL goes to GitHub Gist which just displays the text, I didn't know URL must be download URL. I opted for local file since I didn't manage to get this working at the time..

Comment: Ok, in the future, if you want to see whether the page is correctly fetching the KML file, you can use the Chrome Developer Tools, look at the Network tab, and filter by ".km" (to see .kml and .kmz files).  Then reload the page (or make the code fetch the file), and you should see the request and whether it correctly fetches the file or not.